# AlertDialog is shown blank

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to open up a Layout which has an image inside an `AlertDialog`. But I am getting a blank dialog. Here is my code.

`ImageView.axml` layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/Apple"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```

C# code:

```cs
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
 View dialogLayout = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageView, null);
 dialog.SetView(dialogLayout);
 dialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the Image file size in the drawable folder. Size of the image was too big. When I try an image with smaller size it is working.

Comment: Was the smaller image filename all lowercase?  If so, I would try renaming "Apple.png" to "apple.png" (and updating the "src=" entry accordingly) and giving that a go again as drawable resource filenames should be lowercase (if not, you will experience issues, such as GetIdentifier() returning a zero).  I updated my answer with that suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code using the latest version of Xamarin and I can see the image in the Dialog Box.  So, I'm betting you don't have an "Apple.png" image file in your Resources/drawable folder.  If you do, try another png file and/or ensure the "BuildAction" for that image is set to "AndroidResource".

Also, drawable resources should be all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm), create() is called after setting the View. I know out of habit, I always call create() and then show() last. Hope that helps.